# Hive - Convert GMT timestamp to IST

Tags: hive, timestamp, timezone

I have an external Hive table. I want to convert the timestamp from GMT to IST. But all of the hive functions are showing convert from and convert to UTC only.

In my table, the source data stored in GMT timezone.

#### Sample Data:

```
hive> select d_date from hive_table limit 3;
OK
2017-06-01 06:49:46
2017-06-02 11:41:36
2017-06-07 10:34:00
```

Can someone help to convert this to UTC?

Comment: By "IST", do you mean "Irish Standard Time", "Israel Standard Time", "India Standard Time", "Iran Standard Time" or something else?  Not all Time zone abbreviations are all unique identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`from_utc_timestamp`** with your **`timezone`**.

```
select from_utc_timestamp(<col_name>,"Asia/Kolkata");
```